# textbox access for datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, datepicker, this

I'm using a date picker jQuery plugin created by Stefan Petre and available here:

http://www.eyecon.ro/datepicker/#about

This is a code I'm using to apply datepicker to textboxes

```
 $('.tableMstCellECD').DatePicker({
            format: 'd/m/Y',
            date: $('.tableMstCellECD').val(),
            current: $('.tableMstCellECD').val(),
            calendars: 3,
            onChange: function (formated, dates) {
                $('.tableMstCellECD').val(formated);
                $('.tableMstCellECD').DatePickerHide();
            }
        });
```

It works fine, but obviously updates values of all textboxes instead of selected one. The problem is that there can be different number of texboxes so I cannot hard code access values. I was trying to implement "this" keyword somewhere into this command but did not succeed

Comment: why dont you use this normal and easy one : http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/ ... its quite easy and has all features

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with  Deepanshu, you should use jQuery UI. If you want to avoid that for some reason, KarelG's solution works just fine, however since you already include jQuery, you can write it like that:

```
$('.tableMstCellECD').each(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
    $(this).DatePicker({
        format: 'd/m/Y',
        date: $('#' + id).val(),
        current: $('#' + id).val(),
        calendars: 1,
        onChange: function (formated, dates) {
            $('#' + id).val(formated);
            $('#' + id).DatePickerHide();
        }
    });
});
```

You also have to generate unique ID-s for the input elements either on the server or the client side, like this:

```
<input type="text" id="01" class="tableMstCellECD" />
<input type="text" id="02" class="tableMstCellECD" />
<input type="text" id="03" class="tableMstCellECD" />
<input type="text" id="04" class="tableMstCellECD" />
```

Answer (score 0):

i also have this problem before. So i wrote an own script (in js) to implement it to textboxes which contains only the class name "datepicker" or something different. To provide support to most browser, i have done it by this way ;

```
/*
* === javascript file to implement datepicker on form fields for dates
*
* @author : Karel Geiregat
* @version : 1.0.4 - 18 may 2013
*/

// class name which contains input box, chosen for dates
var comparerString = "datepicker";

// get all inputfields, select only those marked with right class name
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
    // select all input boxes
    var getElements = document.getElementsByTagName("input");
    // check count
    var count = getElements.length;
    // loop through elements
    for(var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
        // get classname - supported by most major browsers
        if (getElements[i].className == comparerString) {
            var idField = "#" + getElements[i].id;
            $(idField).datepicker({ dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd" });
        }
    }
});
```

and in HTML

```
<input id="form_startDate" class="datepicker" type="text" required="required">
```

Just write something similar in jQuery. Just add a class name to the textbox which should be tagged with the DatePicker object.

Comment: Unfortunately your method worked correctly for the last textbox only for me